# Schedule job based on parameter?

Tags: jenkins

I'd like to start a build for a job named project-${X} where ${X} is given by a parameter of the current build. Does this work, maybe with a plugin?

Thanks,
Carsten

Answer (score 0):

[Parameterized Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) has that feature. You need to use the latest version (2.15) - there seems to be a bug in earlier versions.

Your other options seem to be [Python JenkinsAPI wrapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkinsapi) or Groovy run via [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) that accesses Jenkins via its [Java API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: Worked for me. Installing [Token Macro Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Token+Macro+Plugin) may help. Which version of Jenkins are you using?